# Show flash while buffering?

Tags: html, flash

i'm developing a web where i want to show a flash on the index page. The flash got 3Mb size. But while it is downloading, i just see a white space where it should be.

I have tried putting an image in the background, but i just see white until the flash is fully downloaded...

Any tip? I would like to see the first image of the flash, or an static image while it is loading?

im just putting it in the direct way

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="899" height="138">
```

`<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="899" height="138">
  <param name="movie" value="FELIPE.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <embed src="FELIPE.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="899" height="138"></embed>
</object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your environment, flex, flex builder, flash, etc, the method will be different.  But what you are looking for is a 'preloader'.   You move all your resources out of the first frame and move it to the second frame, the movie will load the first frame fast, display your 'loading message', then stop, and actionscript runs checking for the load progress of the swf, when it is complete, it advances to the second frame and plays your movie.

Comment: No idea about enviroment, im just using a flash the client gave to me... So hard to put a fixed image until the flash is downloaded?

Comment: If you don't have access to modify the swf (which you would need for an internal preloader).  You can try using an external preloader swf, but depending on what the swf does, and its actionscript it might not run correctly.  The only other idea I have is for you to put it in a div which has a css background picture that says loading, and change the swf to wmode=transparent, but thats really a stretch.  I'm sorry but flash doesn't really have any preloader (with or without progressbar) by default, you must code your own...

Comment: MM could you explain that 'change the swf to wmode=transparent'? I that can be done i could just a background image (the first frame of the flash, a simple screen capture) The only thinh g i want is the user dont see a white space for long. And how would i do the flash opaque again?

Comment: You would need to add <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> below the <param name="quality">, and add wmode="transparent" to the <embed> tag after the height="" parameter.  This will allow the default background color to become transparent.  Next step is to use css to set a background image for the <div> that contains this object/embed tag.  In theory this should work, however if your swf doesn't contain a background it will look odd when it loads, I don't believe you can change the wmode after it is loaded, its a browser function.  As I said, this method is not ideal.

Comment: The last thing I can suggest is to put a footnote below the movie saying 'Please be patient while the movie loads...'.  The ideal solution is to talk to your flash developer and have him incorporate a preloader into the swf.

Comment: As explained in my first comment, another option is to try and do a wrapper swf... Well I know that some swf code protectors wrap your swf internally into another swf, and they have the option of adding a preloader.  If you look at software like http://www.swfprotection.com/addpreloadertoflash.html  you'll see they can load your swf inside theirs and add a preloader progress bar while it loads as well as protecting your code.  They offer a demo, but the software is commercial.

Comment: Will try all your solutions, you are great Superafro.

Comment: Hi again Superafro. Finnaly, as you said, i contacted a frind who is flash expert and he made an external preloader for me. Without your help, i didnt even know such thing existence :)